# How do I access data from an lvm volume on a drive?

Tags: linux, mount, proxmox, lvm

I have an SSD from a failed server with data on it I'd like to restore. The data is in an LVM volume. I've tried various things based on googling which may have messed things up on the drive but I'm hoping I can still recover some of it.  Here is what I have:

```
root@proxmox:~# lsblk --fs
NAME                                FSTYPE      FSVER    LABEL UUID                                   FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINTS
sda                                 LVM2_member LVM2 001       qpcyWo-27I7-nEuH-X4P2-F1f6-FIko-owcvSM                
├─InternalSATA-InternalSATA_tmeta                                                                                    
│ └─InternalSATA-InternalSATA-tpool                                                                                  
│   └─InternalSATA-InternalSATA                                                                                      
└─InternalSATA-InternalSATA_tdata                                                                                    
  └─InternalSATA-InternalSATA-tpool                                                                                  
    └─InternalSATA-InternalSATA                                                                                      
nvme0n1                                                                                                              
├─nvme0n1p1                                                                                                          
├─nvme0n1p2                         vfat        FAT32          D981-86BE                              1010.4M     1% /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p3                         LVM2_member LVM2 001       jAX3nn-NSA0-F5mG-Bhuq-KNK0-bPbK-UMkz13                
│ ├─pve-swap                        swap        1              c5a8a76b-e6ca-4820-b1ef-dcbbbf51f486                  [SWAP]
│ ├─pve-root                        ext4        1.0            56fd52d8-fcc2-4918-b9fd-7e3ddd436dfd     83.1G     6% /
│ ├─pve-data_tmeta                                                                                                   
│ │ └─pve-data                                                                                                       
│ └─pve-data_tdata                                                                                                   
│   └─pve-data                                                                                                       
└─nvme0n1p4                         LVM2_member LVM2 001       1ks11c-Uqg6-Qq9l-Fne2-pgGN-NQiR-ErKzXJ                
  └─Pool1-vm--100--disk--0
```

where **sda** / **InternalSATA** is the drive I'm interested in.

More info:

```
root@proxmox:~# lvs -o +lv_health_status
  LV            VG           Attr       LSize    Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert Health         
  InternalSATA  InternalSATA twi-aotz--   <3.61t             0.00   0.19                                            
  vm-100-disk-0 Pool1        -wi-a-----  512.00g                                                                    
  data          pve          twi-a-tz-- <383.18g             0.00   0.44                                            
  root          pve          -wi-ao----   96.00g                                                                    
  swap          pve          -wi-ao----    8.00g
```

```
root@proxmox:~# pvck /dev/sda
  Found label on /dev/sda, sector 1, type=LVM2 001
  Found text metadata area: offset=4096, size=1044480
```

```
root@proxmox:~# vgscan 
  Found volume group "Pool1" using metadata type lvm2
  Found volume group "pve" using metadata type lvm2
  Found volume group "InternalSATA" using metadata type lvm2
```

```
root@proxmox:~# lvscan
  ACTIVE            '/dev/Pool1/vm-100-disk-0' [512.00 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/pve/data' [<383.18 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/pve/swap' [8.00 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/pve/root' [96.00 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/InternalSATA/InternalSATA' [<3.61 TiB] inherit
```

```
root@proxmox:~# ls -l /dev/mapper/
total 0
crw------- 1 root root 10, 236 Mar 29 18:45 control
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Mar 29 19:12 InternalSATA-InternalSATA -> ../dm-9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Mar 29 19:12 InternalSATA-InternalSATA_tdata -> ../dm-6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Mar 29 19:12 InternalSATA-InternalSATA_tmeta -> ../dm-5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Mar 29 19:12 InternalSATA-InternalSATA-tpool -> ../dm-8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Mar 29 18:45 Pool1-vm--100--disk--0 -> ../dm-0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Mar 29 18:45 pve-data -> ../dm-7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Mar 29 18:45 pve-data_tdata -> ../dm-4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Mar 29 18:45 pve-data_tmeta -> ../dm-3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Mar 29 18:45 pve-root -> ../dm-2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Mar 29 18:45 pve-swap -> ../dm-1
```

```
root@proxmox:~# ls -l /dev/I*
ls: cannot access '/dev/I*': No such file or directory
```

```
root@proxmox:~# mount /dev/mapper/InternalSATA-InternalSATA_tdata /mnt
mount: /mnt: /dev/mapper/InternalSATA-InternalSATA_tdata already mounted or mount point busy.
       dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.
```

```
[ 4210.222189] /dev/mapper/InternalSATA-InternalSATA_tdata: Can't open blockdev
```

```
root@proxmox:~# vgdisplay
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               Pool1
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  2
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                1
  Open LV               0
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               <1.32 TiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              345859
  Alloc PE / Size       131072 / 512.00 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       214787 / 839.01 GiB
  VG UUID               eTPcZ4-uSpo-2N1J-08BD-9Jtu-6Ce7-9QWCu2
   
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               pve
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  7
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                3
  Open LV               2
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               <511.00 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              130815
  Alloc PE / Size       126718 / 494.99 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       4097 / 16.00 GiB
  VG UUID               9VHiqW-TBms-12uM-IHse-mVa5-144h-eFf4Iu
   
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               InternalSATA
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  10
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                1
  Open LV               0
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               <3.64 TiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              953861
  Alloc PE / Size       953767 / <3.64 TiB
  Free  PE / Size       94 / 376.00 MiB
  VG UUID               LaHQqD-zQeP-L03l-h31M-7iQd-qb6Z-J7a1KJ
```

```
root@proxmox:~# lvdisplay 
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/Pool1/vm-100-disk-0
  LV Name                vm-100-disk-0
  VG Name                Pool1
  LV UUID                QT933n-MeqI-sD0P-R3ll-Ua0H-KH83-6LqeEp
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time proxmox, 2024-03-29 15:49:15 -0800
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                512.00 GiB
  Current LE             131072
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           252:0
   
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Name                data
  VG Name                pve
  LV UUID                L7WmAq-VhiB-MCpH-AKIS-KukK-PEBv-uUhrUD
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time proxmox, 2024-03-29 15:24:06 -0800
  LV Pool metadata       data_tmeta
  LV Pool data           data_tdata
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                <383.18 GiB
  Allocated pool data    0.00%
  Allocated metadata     0.44%
  Current LE             98094
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           252:7
   
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/pve/swap
  LV Name                swap
  VG Name                pve
  LV UUID                0Dm4bB-xx3L-XfKJ-CLKf-V1JP-fXLY-Im2qhb
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time proxmox, 2024-03-29 15:24:04 -0800
  LV Status              available
  # open                 2
  LV Size                8.00 GiB
  Current LE             2048
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           252:1
   
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/pve/root
  LV Name                root
  VG Name                pve
  LV UUID                LE0LmS-weWz-VF6K-CfmD-Me39-WoJh-llzQkd
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time proxmox, 2024-03-29 15:24:04 -0800
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                96.00 GiB
  Current LE             24576
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           252:2
   
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Name                InternalSATA
  VG Name                InternalSATA
  LV UUID                QyhZqX-xmKZ-Hs4U-MVFo-H13c-c8kK-RXW41T
  LV Write Access        read/write (activated read only)
  LV Creation host, time proxmox, 2024-02-07 17:05:55 -0900
  LV Pool metadata       InternalSATA_tmeta
  LV Pool data           InternalSATA_tdata
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                <3.61 TiB
  Allocated pool data    0.00%
  Allocated metadata     0.19%
  Current LE             945637
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           252:9
```

Notice there is no **LV Path** entry for **InternalSATA**

What can I try from here?  I'm not very experienced with lvm (or Proxmox)...

Thanks.